# VS2012 MVC4 Template - cannot debug website 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, http-status-code-404

I am having what I think is a weird issue.
After re-installing (because it did the same thing before) VS2012 I am unable to debug websites on my local machine - running Windows 7 Pro SP1

When I create a new application of the type Internet Application I can debug fine - I mean it brings up the website in the browser.

When I select the Basic template I get a 404 error (See Image 2)
Even after I create a Model, a Controller and a View.

Despite it being an empty website - when the view is created it has the `<h2>Index</h2>` so it show that at a minimum.

Am I making a bonehead simple error that gives me the error? The setup in my projects are exactly the same, so I do not really understand what gives me this error.

[image: Image 01]

[image: Image02]

Answer (score 0):

So after finding [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/418372/The-resource-cannot-be-found) and following the instructions it worked.

I needed to create a HomeController with an index page.
I had done everything except naming the Controller - HomeController